# Basic questions about Java CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath

Suppose I just created a package "example" and have two classes inside it, "Main" and "Helper".

With the simplest possible compilation (e.g., $javac Main.java Helper.java) I am already able to run it fine as long as I am in the directory containing the example package, by typing this in the command line:

```
$java example.Main
```

Questions:

1. Why would I want to set a CLASSPATH given I can already run the program? I am guessing to be able to type "$java example.Main" from any directory on my machine, but I am not sure.
2. What happens when I type "java -cp /path/to/your/java/class/file Main" on the command line? Right now I picture there's file containing all the different classpaths, and that command will just add another one to it. Is it the case?
3. Is there a difference between using "CLASSPATH=/path/to/your/java/class/file" and "java -cp /path/to/your/java/class/file Main" on the command line? How come the second one has the name of the class (i.e. Main) in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yea, pretty much. That of course assumes you have the path to `java` in your `PATH` variable
2. -cp or -classpath adds it's option (a string) in front of whatever is in your `CLASSPATH`
3. Yes, there is a difference. Using `CLASSPATH` is often more convenient as you tend to set your `CLASSPATH` once. From then on, `java Main` is enough to execute the main class. With `java -cp /path/to/your/java/class/file Main` you have to type the `-cp /path/to/your/java/class/file` every time.

That being said, both `CLASSPATH` and `-cp` or `-classpath` options usually contain entries pointing to directories containing java libraries used by your program, not the directory of your program itself.

Comment: 1. is not quite correct. From a different directory he would have to set his classpath since if not other specified the classpath is assumed to be the current working directory.

Comment: I was under the impression that the question was "Why should I set my `CLASSPATH` variable? So I can run the program from any directory on my system?" In that case, the `CLASSPATH` would be set.

Comment: But indeed good addition to mention that the classpath is assumed to be the current working directory, thanks